# physical address of objects in C#

Tags: c#

I am storing objects of classes in secondary storage. For faster access of these obejcts I want to know the physical address of each objects. 
How to get physical address of objects in Csharp.net?
What is the meaning of `GetHashCode()` function in C#.NET? 
Is it related to  physical address of object?

There are two methods which will access the data from database: Full Scan and Bplustree. To search for a record from database if  I am using full scan method then it will be wastage of time. If I am using Bplustree then for every attribute I have to create bplusTree which will occupy the space.
  So I need a method which will be in between. If I am able to access a physical address of an object. Then I can directly retrieve that record. That is why Above question is asked. 
  If anyone is having another idea then it is most welcome.

Comment: You can use pointer but you have to made code unsafe, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/y31yhkeb.aspx

Comment: Um, physical addressing requires a driver, and it is actually slower than virtual addressing since you first have to create a virtual mapping for it. What is the actual problem you are having where you think that getting a physical address will help?

Comment: You are trying to solve a problem which does not exist.

Comment: By "secondary storage", are you talking about tape? Do you need the physical address because you're trying to do DMA?

Comment: Physical memory access is not suggested in C# program if you want to improve your application performance check [this] out
[this]:http://www.dotnetperls.com/optimization

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to get physical addresses when using a language like C# usually. C# is higher level language that is meant to abstract out low-level operations like memory management.

`GetHashCode()` is meant to return a hash code, i.e. an identifier of an object that is used to distinguish one instance of a class from another instance. It has nothing to do with the physical address. Check more here on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx